HTML elements go black when loading
After going black they momentarily go back to normal.

Loading....

Here is the code of the navbar.
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Curriculum</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Curriculum.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" async></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true" async></script>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Curriculum</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    @if(User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                    {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Roles" asp-action="Index">Roles</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Courses" asp-action="Index">Courses</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Groups" asp-action="Index">Groups</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Teachers" asp-action="Index">Teachers</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
                <partial name="_LoginPartial"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <main role="main" class="pb-3">
        @RenderBody()
    </main>
</div>

@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
<footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
    <div class="container">
        &copy; 2024 - Curriculum - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>

If I spam the navigation button main page background goes black too sometimes.
It may be because of scripts. I tried changing the place of scripts: after the body, in the head. I also tried adding an async attribute to scripts, no result.

Does it happen if you remove the <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true" async></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Curriculum.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>?

Does this issue occur after some changes or it exists all the time? By the way, does this issue occur in all the browsers or a specific browser? And have you tried to clear the cache or test in a private window?

I tried using Opera GX and Edge, but the issue doesn't appear there. I also tried using a private window in Chrome, and the issue does appear there, so it seems the problem is with Chrome.

Thanks for your confirmation. Does the issue occurred after any code changing?

I can't say exactly when the issue started to appear, as I was focused on other functionality. Any insights on what might be causing this would be helpful.

This issue looks to be a browser-specific issue so that it's hard to say what codes have issues related to compatibility. The best approach is to find out the changes when the issue occurred. It shall related to CSS or HTML.

Try deleting these lines of code if you are not using them
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Curriculum.styles.css" asp-append-version="true"/>

If it doesn't work, check what they are doing in the back and if they could be causing a conflict.
These stylesheets are probably causing the problem.

site.css and Curriculum.style.css are basically empty and bootstrap.min.css is too big to go through. removing them basically removes all style from page and in some way fixes my problem but no. Edit: i tried clicking without css and background still go black.
